# How to remove Gap between textbox and Keyboard in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am creating a chat window with text box in the bottom and send bottom. when i click on text box keyboard is appearing, but is showing the gap between text box and keyboard. how to remove the gap  between text box and Keyboard in windows phone

Comment: problem snap please. Otherwise here we will throw in air as you did

Comment: I try ed to add the snap but i don't have the access to upload snap

Answer (score 0):

Good news! I have managed to figure out a fix for this. The below code stops the page from being moved up at all and then adds a margin to the bottom of the text box to place it above the keyboard. The value below of 417 seems to work well for me but you can change this to whatever you like. Using this method also stops other content being pushed off screen like the conversation as it will be fully scrollable while the keyboard is active.

```
private void TextBox_GotFocus_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var rootFrame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
        rootFrame.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform() { TranslateY = +0 };
        TextInput2.Margin = new Thickness(12, 0, 12, 417);
    }

private void TextBox_LostFocus_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var rootFrame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
        rootFrame.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform() { TranslateY = +0 };
        TextInput2.Margin = new Thickness(12, 0, 12, 12);
    }
```